# Can we characterize the plot of a (not necessarily continuous) function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, graphing-functions, approximation-theory

Given $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, what can we say about its *plot* (that is, about what a sketch of its graph may look like)? Continuous functions are often described as "functions we can draw the graph of" - can we make this more precise?  What about discontinuous functions like $x \mapsto \sin (1/x)$ or the [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function)?  Or pathological functions such as those dense in the plane?

An initial attempt:

Given a function, define its *graph* $G$ as $G(f) = \{(x, f(x)) : x \in \mathbb R\}$.  Given a graph $G \subseteq \mathbb R^2$, then $P \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is a *plot* of $G$ if both the following conditions are met:

1. $G \subseteq P$
2. $P$ is the arbitrary union of open balls, each of which:
   a. Has a constant diameter $w$ (called the *pen-width* of $P$)
   b. Includes at least one point from $G$ (that is, $G \cap B \neq \emptyset$).

Consequently:

- Most functions can have many plots of the same pen-width.  Question: Are there functions that for a given pen-width admit only one plot?
- The plot of a continuous function seems to match our intuition
- The plot of the Dirichlet function is equal to $P(G(x \mapsto 0)) \cup P(G(x \mapsto 1))$, as we'd expect.  ($P$ is not a function but is used similar  to big-$O$ notation.)
- The plot of a function dense in the plane is, at any pen-width, the plane itself
- I do not know how to characterize the plot of $x \mapsto \sin(1/x)$ or $x \mapsto x \sin(1/x)$
- Given a plot, can we always tell if it is the plot of a continuous function? For what pen-widths do discontinuous functions take on continuous plots? What is the relationship between plots, continuity, and differentiability?
- Is there a way to tighten the definition of plot so that for a given pen-width a function has only one plot?
- Does the definition work well for higher dimensions and other metric spaces?

This question is not limited to those questions: Any reasonable definition of a plot of a function or discussion of its properties is responsive.

Comment: This paper may be relevant: https://www.math.uh.edu/~hjm/restricted/pdf36(3)/16lewis.pdf